# Reduction in Proof about Linear Comb. of Measurable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> For a measurable subset $D$ of $E$, $f$ is measurable on $E$ if and only if the restriction of $f$ to $D$ and $E-D$ are measurable.

Here is a passage from the book I am reading:

[image]

Here is the theorem whose proof I am trying to understand:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be measurable functions on $E$ that are finite almost every on $E$. For any $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\alpha f + \beta g$ is measurable on $E$.

Here is another quote: [image]

Why does it suffice to assume that $f$ and $g$ are finite on all of $E$? Presumably the author means to say that, if we can show that $f+g$ is measurable on $E_0$, then any extension of $f+g$ to all of $E$ is also measurable, as he did in the first quote. But isn't $f+g$ trivially measurable over $E_0$, since $E_0$ is of zero measure. If that's the case, why shouldn't we be trying to show measurability over $E-E_0$? I am having a difficult time seeing how all ideas go into reducing the problem to assuming that $f$ and $g$ are finite over all of $E$.

Comment: $E-E_0$ is of measure zero, because $f,g$ are finite a.e. on $E$, and $E_0$ is the set where $f,g$ are finite.

Comment: @EclipseSun Not according to my book. "Recall that a property is said to hold almost everywhere on a measurable set provided it holds on $E-E_0$, where $E_0 \subseteq E$ for which $m(E_0)=0$." However, I did mistakenly think was finite on $E_0$. Now that I reread the definition of "almost everywhere", I now see why it suffices to prove measurability over $E-E_0$.

Comment: $f,g$ finite a.e. on $E$ means $f,g$ is not finite on a set of measure zero. The symbol $E_0$ is not the same in your definition and in the picture you pasted above.